# How can I have continuous hover color over table row?

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have the following table which is being created inside my asp.net web application:

```css
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #eeeeea;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table class='table' style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:1em;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='text-align:left'></th>
      <th style='text-align:right'>Pages</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>objectives</td>
      <td>3<td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I hover over a table row, I get the following effect:

[image: screenshot]

Where there will be a white area between the table `<td>` as shown above.. So can anyone advice on this please? How can I define a continuous hover over my entire table row?

I've tried setting the following to change the border color on hover, but this has no effect:

```css
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #eeeeea;
  border-color: #eeeeea;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML looks like it was cut off.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i only show part of it.. i updated my question with more html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gap is from `border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:1em;` on the `table`, change that to `border-collapse:collapse;`, and use `padding` on `th` and `td` for spacing as needed.

Side note, you forgot to close the second `<td>` in the markup.

```css
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table class='table' style='border-collapse:collapse;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='text-align:left'></th>
      <th style='text-align:right'>Pages</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>objectives</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to colour the row its self, and make the cells transparent.

```
.table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeea;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.table tbody tr td, .table tbody tr th {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but this will not solve my problem

Comment: I fail to understand how this would not help. Could you please explain why? Maybe I can come up with another suggestion.